# get Missing Rectangle Point ? How can i reduce the time complexity of this code?

Tags: python, algorithm

Here  I wrote the code to find the missing coordinate of a rectangle from the coordinates of rectangle.

```
def getMissingRectanglePoint(rectangle):
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    for  i in rectangle:
        list1.append(i[0])
        list2.append(i[1])
    x=None
    y=None
    for i in list1:
        if(list1.count(i) % 2):
            x=i 
            break
    for i in list2:
        if(list2.count(i) % 2):
            y=i
            break

    return [x,y]
    

no_of_testcases=int(input())

for i in range(0,no_of_testcases):
    
    no_of_rectangles=int(input())
    cordinates=[]
    
    for i in range(0,(4*no_of_rectangles-1)):
        
        cordinates.append(list(input().split(" ")))
        
    cord1=getMissingRectanglePoint(cordinates)
    
    print(cord1[0],cord1[1])
```

here are inputs as per the code:

```
1
2
1 1
1 2
4 6
2 1
9 6
9 3
4 3
```

And the o/p of this is:

```
2,2
```

Suggest the best way to reduce the time required in execution of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scan lists seeking for every value many times. Instead you can count occurence of every coordinate value using dictionary approach.

```
import collections
def getMissingRectanglePoint(coords):
    dx = collections.Counter()
    dy = collections.Counter()
    for coord in coords:
        dx[coord[0]] += 1
        dy[coord[1]] += 1
    for xx in dx:
        if dx[xx] % 2 == 1:
            mx = xx
            break
    for yy in dy:
        if dy[yy] % 2 == 1:
            my = yy
            break
    return [mx, my]
```

Comment: but still its not that efficient as it is required, i want this code to get completed in 1sec or less than  2 second.  for |x|,|y|≤10^5

Comment: Consider not using `cordinates` list - treat every line